Ajax form handling problem - embedded ajax call
First of all, sorry for any language errors, I used google translate.
I work on an mvc interface, including the installer script.
I have divided the installation process into several parts:

Creating a database server
Server setting
SMTP server consent

In the server setting, the time zone and system administrator data
Since setting up the database is a multi-step process, I used ajax to manage the processing of the data entered in the form, and then the management of the further process phase. At the end of each phase, I write its status in a div, whether it is in progress, successful, or unsuccessful. This way, I can more easily track if there is a blockage somewhere, and even if a process is slower, I can still see exactly what is working. Once closed, it calls the new form, which it loads in place of the previous one.
It works perfectly fine up to this point, but the new form no longer detects ajax. There is no error message. I also tried a new ajax handling code in the server settings form. but does not start it. I checked with alert(), that code is loaded, but the ajax response no longer occurs when I click on the submit button.
I also thought about ob_start(), but unfortunately it doesn't work, it only prints the data at the very end of the script execution, not during it. That's why I stayed with ajax.
The ajax code:
$( document ).ready( function() {  
  
    var jQueryInstallForm   = "#jqInstallForm";  
    var outputContent       = "#outputContent";  
    var workingContent      = "#working";  
    var mainContent         = "#installContent";  
  
    $( jQueryInstallForm ).submit( function(e){  
        var targetSelf = "#content";  
        var jQFormControll = "source";  
        var $controll = ( $( jQueryInstallForm ).data( jQFormControll ) ) ? "#" + $( jQueryInstallForm ).data( jQFormControll ) : targetSelf;  
        var $dest = ( typeof $( this ).attr( 'data-dest' ) === 'undefined' ) ? 'working' : $( this ).attr( 'data-dest' );  
        var $data = $( this ).serialize().replace( /(\.\.%2F\.\.)/gi, "" );  
  
        $( "#submit" ).prop( 'disabled', true );  
  
        $.ajax({  
            url:        $( this ).attr( 'action' ),  
            type:       $( this ).attr( 'method' ),  
            data:       $data,  
            mimeType:   "multipart/form-data",  
  
/* Create database */  
            success: function( response ) {  
                var jsonResponse = false;  
                jsonResponse = convertToJSON( response );  
  
                if ( jsonResponse !== false ) {  
                    response = jsonResponse;  
                } else {  
                    var response = {"html": response};  
                    $( mainContent ).html( response.html );  
                }  
  
                $( $controll ).append( response.html );  
                $( workingContent ).html( 'Install/setInstallStatus/1' );  
  
                if ( typeof response.installer !== 'undefined' ) {  
                    $.ajax({  
                        url: response.url,  
/* Create tables */  
                        success: function( response ) {  
                            jsonResponse = convertToJSON( response );  
  
                            if ( jsonResponse != false ) {  
                                response = jsonResponse;  
  
                                var result = createStatus( "Create tables", response );  
  
                                if ( result === "0" ) {  
                                    return false;  
                                }  
  
                                $( workingContent ).html( 'Install/setInstallStatus/1' );  
                            } else {  
                                var response = {"html":response};  
                            }  
  
                            $( $controll ).append( response.html );  
  
  
                            $.ajax({  
                                url: response.url,  
/* Upload data to database */  
                                success: function( response ) {  
                                    jsonResponse = convertToJSON( response );  
  
                                    if ( jsonResponse !== false ) {  
                                        response = jsonResponse;  
  
                                        var result = createStatus( "Load data to database", response );  
  
                                        if ( result === "0" ) {  
                                            return false;  
                                        }  
  
                                        $( workingContent ).html( 'Install/setInstallStatus/2' );  
                                        $( mainContent ).html( response.html );  
                                    } else {  
                                        var response = {"html":response};  
                                        $( $controll ).append( response.html );  
                                    }  
                                }  
                            });  
                        }  
                    });  
                }  
            }  
        });  
  
        return false;  
    });  
});  
  
function createStatus( text, response ) {  
    var $status, $class;  
    var lastChar = response.progress[response.progress.length -1];  
                                      
    if ( response.status == "1") {  
        $status = "<i>Done.</i>";  
        $class  = "Success";  
    } else {  
        $status = "<i><b>Error!</b></i>";  
        $class  = "Error";  
    }  
  
    $( ".outputTitle" + lastChar ).html( "<b>" + text + " (" + response.totalCount + "/" + response.count + " hiba: " + response.errorCount + "):</b>" );  
    $( "." + response.progress ).attr( 'id', 'ctrlDispMessageStatus' + $class );  
    $( "." + response.progress ).html( $status );  
  
    if ( response.status !== "1") {  
        $( "#submit" ).prop( 'disabled', false );  
        return "0";  
    } else {  
        return "1";  
    }  
}

I tried to put the repetitive part of the code in a separate function to make it more uniform, but it didn't work that way. Also, write a separate procedure for the mail settings, but the ajax part did not want to run

If the new form replaces the old form you'll need to add the event listener to the new form. The old one was removed when the form was removed.

you should use e.preventDefault(), rather than disabling the submit button..

@MisterJojo they disable it while doing the ajax only

You need to delegate. Change $( jQueryInstallForm ).submit( function(e){ .... to $('selectorOfClosestStaticContainer').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ....;

Thank you very much for your help!
The script file was originally in the header section, now I moved it so that it always loads with the given form, and now it works! :)

@mplungjan I originally did it this way, but the script didn't work properly, and there was an error message in chrome that it was another unused function...

What I suggest IS the way to do this. So better fix what did not work than to keep adding the event listeners again and again

@mplungjam I completely agree with you, but the problem is that if I put it in the  section, for some reason the script is only called once...
The first form is loaded into the "installContent" div.
After filling out, the script runs normally, at the end of which a new form is loaded into "installContent", replacing the previous form. When I also send it, the script doesn't run again, as if it wasn't loaded.

You need to attach the event listener to the nearest static container. that is the div which is NOT changed by Ajax

@mplungjam I also did it by loading the script file into an eyg div, but unfortunately the result is the same... the new form is no longer handled


